# Union in JPA and using Alias

Tags: spring-data-jpa, union, hibernate-mapping, nativequery

I have 2 entites, **PERSON** and **PEOPLE**

**PERSON** has columns namely -> FN, LN

**PEOPLE** has columns -> FIRST, LAST

I want to fetch the union of both the tables together. How do I do it in JPA.
I have used the below way:

Created a new DTO -> **Human** having 2 fields FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME (case sensitive)

```
@Query(value=" SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM "+
  "(  SELECT "+
  "      P.FN AS FIRSTNAME, "+
  "      P.LN AS LASTNAME " +
  " FROM PERSON P"+
  " UNION "+
  " SELECT "+
  "      A.FIRST AS FIRSTNAME, "+
  "      A.LAST AS LASTNAME ' +
  " FROM PEOPLE A"+
  ")", nativeQuery = true)
Pageable<Human>  getEntireHumanRace() {
.... 
}
```

The SQL runs fine, but the ORM always forms a malformed SQL
such as "Syntax error in SQL statement SELECT COUNT(P) FROM PERSON P ...."
InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement

Is there any suggestion on what can be done? Why does it put the count in front of the generated query?
Appreciate in advance.

Comment: Show your Human class and code with your repository.

Comment: Human is just a DTO class with no mapping with Entity.

Comment: Why you are using `Pageable`, you are not passing `pageable` obj right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does it put the count in front of the generated query?

Because you are trying to get data with pagination (`Pageable`). So for total element count Count query executing.

> Is there any suggestion on what can be done?

You are using class-based projection and use `List<Human>`

```
@Query(value="SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM ...")
List<Human> getEntireHumanRace();
```